# How to Rename Certain Observations in Column Based on Certain String Value?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm looking to rename certain values of my column based upon a certain string.
My current data resembles this example:

```
PlayerID

Hank_Aaron+7
Babe Ruth+5
MMM + 7
Willie Mayes+1
MMM + 3
```

I would like to rename all observations that start with "MMM" to be just "MMM". For example, I want the above table to ultimately look like this:

```
PlayerID

Hank_Aaron+7
Babe Ruth+5
MMM
Willie Mayes+1
MMM
```

I also need to keep the column in the same dataframe so that I can use it for regressions. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `grep`, find the position index of 'MMM' string, extract those, then do an assignment (assuming 'PlayerID' is `character` class and not `factor` class)

```
df1$PlayerID[grep("^MMM", df1$PlayerID)] <- "MMM"
```

Comment: Wow, that seems to have done it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `startsWith` :

```
df$PlayerID[startsWith(df$PlayerID, 'MMM')] <- 'MMM'
```

We can also use this in `replace` :

```
df$PlayerID <- replace(df$PlayerID, startsWith(df$PlayerID, 'MMM'), 'MMM')
df
#        PlayerID
#1   Hank_Aaron+7
#2    Babe Ruth+5
#3            MMM
#4 Willie Mayes+1
#5            MMM
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(PlayerID = c("Hank_Aaron+7", "Babe Ruth+5", "MMM + 7", 
"Willie Mayes+1", "MMM + 3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Ronak! Is it possible to do this in the opposite direction? For example, what if I wanted to re-name the Player-ID column according to the number at the very end of PlayerID? As such:

```

PlayerID                      NewID
Hank Aaron + 7           7
Babe Ruth + 5             5
Ted Williams + 2          2
Hank Aaron + 5           5

```
Is there maybe an endswith command?

Also if you believe this question merits a new post please let me know.

Comment: There is `endsWith` as well but it needs a fix suffix like "5", or "6" etc, writing this for all combinations can be tiring. So you can use `grepl` here to match with any digit `df$PlayerID[grepl('\\d$', df$PlayerID)] <- 'MMM'`